# Storing Accents and Other Characters in a Database

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I'm working with a `sqlite3` database, selecting certain ID3 info obtained using `mutagen` from mp3s and storing it. When songs contain accents or other "foreign" characters, if I simply attempt to store them as regular Python strings, I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory
that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended     
that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

I therefore encoded all of the strings I was going to store in my database into unicode:

```
            try: # store as unkown if no ID3 info
                songtitle = unicode(audio["TIT2"].__str__(), errors="replace")
            except KeyError:
                songtitle = "Unknown"

            try:
                artist = unicode(audio["TPE1"].__str__(), errors="replace")
            except KeyError:
                artist = "Unknown"

            try:
                album = unicode(audio["TALB"].__str__(), errors="replace")
            except KeyError:
                album = "Unknown"
```

This eliminates all errors and allows the database to be successfully populated. However, it still does not display the accents and other characters, typically replacing them with question marks, spaces, or other garbage characters.

I assume I need to specify some kind of encoding, but I'm not sure how to do that without breaking compatibility with the english encodings etc. As I'm sure you can tell, my experience with encoding is minimal.

Comment: Read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html to learn about what encodings are. Your data is already encoded, you need to *decode* it to Unicode. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2 for info on what codec specifically to use.

Comment: Are you saying they're already encoded when I make the ID3 tag calls to mutagen, or already encoded once I perform the `unicode` operation on them?

Comment: He is sayiing, and so am I, that you shoiçd read that article. Right. Now. joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html - just go there.

Comment: Looking at the Mutagen source code, it looks like it *already* gives you unicode data. You should not need to convert the values to unicode *again*.